# XSL how to count number of nodes depending on value without using attributes?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have done research, but I found only solutions when operating on attributes.

I have recently started to study XSL. I would like to use it to transform my xml file into html one. The data that I want to extract should present how many nodes have certain value.

XML has following structure:

```
<Tests>
    <Test>
        <TestName> a </TestName>
        <Date> 12.11.10 </Date>
        <Result> Fail </Result>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <TestName> b </TestName>
        <Date> 13.11.10 </Date>
        <Result> Fail </Result>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <TestName> c </TestName>
        <Date> 14.11.10 </Date>
        <Result> Pass </Result>
    </Test>
</Tests>
```

what I want as an out is:
2 (number of Fails)
1 (number of Passes)

any could give me a hand with this task ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(Tests/Test[normalize-space(Result)='Fail'])" />
```

Answer (score 3):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kTestByResult" match="Test" use="normalize-space(Result)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(count(key('kTestByResult','Fail')),
                                     ' (number of Fails) ',
                                     count(key('kTestByResult','Pass')),
                                     ' (number of Passes)')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
2 (number of Fails) 1 (number of Passes)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/Tests/Test/Result[normalize-space(text()) = 'Fail'])" />
<xsl:text> (number of Fails)</xsl:text>

<xsl:value-of select="count(/Tests/Test/Result[normalize-space(text()) = 'Pass'])" />
<xsl:text> (number of Passes)</xsl:text>
```